# Can Sitecore rebuild indexes in the background without wiping the existing index?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

Whenever you rebuild a Lucene index in Sitecore the existing index is wiped prior to being rebuilt. This is unacceptable as our indexing process takes a long time (we index at least 100,000 items into a custom product search index).

Does anyone know if you can rebuild a Lucene index through Sitecore in the background then swap indexes when the indexing is complete.

I assume an additional complexity with this approach is what happens to incremental updates during an index rebuild, any insight into how this works in Sitecore would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626640/avoid-removal-of-current-lucene-net-index-during-rebuild

Answer (score 1):

There is a class in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.luceneProvider that caters for this an it is the "Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex"

John West has written a post on it and how to use it at:
http://www.sitecore.net/da-dk/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Rebuild-Lucene-Indexes-in-Temporary-Subdirectories.aspx

There is also an equivalent class for Solr if you happen to use it:
http://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/using-switchonrebuildsolrsearchindex-solr-provider-for-sitecore

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that this is applicable for Sitecore 7, but Sitecore 6.current doesn't seem to support this.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding second index with the same configuration as primary and switch context between those two? E.g. first perform reindex, second- search and switch roles if rebuild required.